# make an angular global resolver to make data available in every route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-resolver

I am trying to make a global resolver which will provide every route... Something like this

`this.activatedRoute.data` =>

```
{
    global: {...}
    route: {...}
}
```

This is what i am trying

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        resolve: { globalResolve: globalResolverService },
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, resolve: { home: ViewHomeResolver } },
            { path: 'getting-started', component: GettingStartedComponent },
            { path: 'expert/:slug', component: ProfileComponent, resolve: { profile: ProfileResolver } },
            { path: 'loan-types', component: Loantype2Component, resolve: { grid: Loan2Resolver } },
            { path: 'loan-types/:loan', component: LoanCategoryDetailsComponent, resolve: { loanDetails: LoanDetailsResolver } },

        ]},
];
```

The above results in the desired outcome only for `homeComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.activatedRoute.data` means you're accessing its own route data scope,

To access the parent data, use `this.activatedRoute.parent.data`